# Place to store a few items in Ayia Napa on day trip from Nicosia (Cyprus)

Tags: luggage-storage, cyprus

I'm going on a trip where I will be staying in Nicosia, Cyprus.  Time prevailing, I'd like to get the bus out to Ayia Napa one day.  Based on [this](http://www.intercity-buses.com/?wp=routes-details&category=&article=&article=9C3ECE385E27B4DF1BE24113F88888A3), it looks like the bus takes about 2 hours from Cyprus to Ayia Napa (4 hour round-trip) and I wouldn't mind taking my laptop along to get some work done on the ride.  The only problem is, I'm not sure if I'd have anywhere to store it once I get there and don't really feel like leaving it on the beach if I go swimming.

My question is, *is there anywhere convenient in Ayia Napa to store such things, whether it be lockers or some other kind of paid storage*?

Answer (score 1):

You can try a hotel.  Many of them will offer luggage storage options for you, even if you don't stay there - you might just pay a small fee. I've done this myself at both hostels and hotels.

I'd suggest calling them beforehand if you want to be sure about it, but it's certainly an option.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you will not be able to find a place to store your things.

I would suggest to ask one of the guys providing umbrellas and other beach facilities, if they would be kind enough to keep your things where they usually have their things.

Unfortunately hotels will not offer you any kind of storage or lockers if you are not one of their guests.